# Not getting proper value or elements with Document​.query​SelectorAll() in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using an "export to .ppt" application where I have used some charts and want to print those charts with the help of a plugin. I need to get all the chart ids in the form of an array and get those ids through `document​.query​SelectorAll()` but I am not getting the proper element ("chart3"). I am getting only first element/chart ("chart1") even though I used the 3rd chart id in the selection array. Here is the code below and a demo link also. On clicking the button you can get the .ppt download.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ROzjhJvOQA1wUoo6XoYI?p=preview

```js
var id = ['chart1', 'chart2', 'chart3'];
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 0;


  Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart1'
    },
    exporting: {
      showTable: true
    },
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
  });

  Highcharts.chart('chart2', {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart2'
    },
    exporting: {
      showTable: true
    },
    series: [{
      data: [3, 2, 3]
    }]
  });

  Highcharts.chart('chart3', {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart3'
    },
    exporting: {
      showTable: true
    },
    series: [{
      data: [3, 2, 7]
    }]
  });
});

function doDemo() {
  console.log(id);
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
  var elements = id;
  var doc = new PptxGenJS();
  for (let i in elements) {
    let svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg');
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let canvasIE = document.createElement('canvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let data1 = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg[i]);
    canvg(canvas, data1);
    let svgBlob = new Blob([data1], {
      type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
    });
    let url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() {
      context.canvas.width = $("#" + elements[i]).find('svg').width();
      context.canvas.height = $("#" + elements[i]).find('svg').height();

      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      // freeing up the memory as image is drawn to canvas
      DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      var dataUrl;
      dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      doc.addNewSlide().addImage({
        data: dataUrl,
        x: 3.0,
        y: 0,
        w: 6.0,
        h: 3.0
      });
    }
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.save('Demo-Images');
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="canvg.js"></script>
<script src="rgbcolor.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/pptxgenjs@2.5.0/dist/pptxgen.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/pptxgenjs@2.5.0/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/pptxgenjs@2.5.0/libs/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/pptxgenjs@2.5.0/dist/pptxgen.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart1"></div>
<div id="chart2"></div>
<div id="chart3"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like you solved it in your plnkr demo. I replaced `var id = ['chart3'];' with `var id = ['chart1', 'chart2', 'chart3'];` and the Generate button created a .ppt with 3 slides, 1 for each chart. Updating the chart 2 `data: [3, 2, 3]` and chart 3 `data: [3, 2, 7]` helps to visualize they are different charts.

Comment: The plnkr IDE also points out `img.onload = function()` should be refactored to a named function outside the loop.

Comment: That is only issue if i use var id = ['chart3'];',then also its printing chart1,its should print chart3 right

Comment: Actually in my application number of charts will be there but I need to export last few charts.Can you please update resolved answer in a separate plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of refactoring and formatting some of your code for readability. Functionality stays the same, just with the fixes to make it work like you wanted.

Fixes:

- Added `let el = elements[i];` to avoid redundant `elements[i]` calls.
- Replaced `document.querySelectorAll('svg')` with `document.querySelectorAll('#' + el + ' svg')` since you just want the specific div's `svg` in each loop, not all the `svg` elements in the doc.
- Replaced `.serializeToString(svg[i])` with `.serializeToString(svg[0])` since there is only 1 element in the array per loop, which will always be the element you want.
- Replaced `$("#" + elements[i]).find('svg')` with `$('#' + el + ' svg')` for some efficiency increase. If we did not have to use `svg = document.querySelectorAll()` per your requirements, we could just use the jQuery selector to assign the variable and reuse the variable again for both `.width()` and `.height()`.

Runnable snippet with external libs at https://next.plnkr.co/edit/mHtNH9DIzhmWOV1U

```js
var id = ['chart3'];

function doDemo() {
  let DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window,
    elements = id,
    doc = new PptxGenJS();

  for (let i in elements) {
    let el = elements[i];
    let svg = document.querySelectorAll('#' + el + ' svg');
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let canvasIE = document.createElement('canvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let data1 = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg[0]);
    canvg(canvas, data1);

    let svgBlob = new Blob([data1], {
      type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
    });
    let url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
    let img = new Image();

    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() {
      context.canvas.width = $('#' + el + ' svg').width();
      context.canvas.height = $('#' + el + ' svg').height();

      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      // freeing up the memory as image is drawn to canvas
      DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      doc.addNewSlide().addImage({
        data: dataUrl,
        x: 3.0,
        y: 0,
        w: 6.0,
        h: 3.0
      });
    }

  };
  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.save('Demo-Images');
  }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart1'
    },
    exporting: {
      showTable: true
    },
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
  });
  Highcharts.chart('chart2', {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart2'
    },
    exporting: {
      showTable: true
    },
    series: [{
      data: [3, 2, 3]
    }]
  });
  Highcharts.chart('chart3', {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart3'
    },
    exporting: {
      showTable: true
    },
    series: [{
      data: [3, 2, 7]
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.chart {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="canvg.js"></script>
<script src="rgbcolor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/pptxgenjs@2.5.0/dist/pptxgen.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/pptxgenjs@2.5.0/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/pptxgenjs@2.5.0/libs/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/pptxgenjs@2.5.0/dist/pptxgen.min.js"></script>

<div class="btntn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success my-4 w-50" onclick="doDemo()">Generate Demo PowerPoint</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="chart" id="chart1"></div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart2"></div>
  <div class="chart" id="chart3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome thanks! However, even with the license I still see the watermark in the Highchart powerpoint slide. Is it possible to remove this?

Comment: @chris For the watermark, you'd have to ask the developer or read the documentation with the product. Typically a valid license automatically hides things like watermarks. It's probably a bug on their end that it does not.

Comment: yes, @OXiGEN the answer was in the documentation, thanks!